Excel legacy wizards disabled after importing txt file
I have a question with regard to the legacy import wizards in Excel.
Nowadays, in our company we work in Excel 365 and although I found the option to enable the legacy wizards under Options>Data, something weird is happening in my file.
I have several sheets in the file, all of which contain some validation, i.e. I have conditional formatting with formulas to check length of the values in each column, to check for correct values (e.g. if only Y/N is allowed) etc. Because of this I need to use the legacy import wizard to import txt files.
But I'm experiencing weird behaviour on my sheets: the legacy import wizard option is greyed out for some. When I create a new sheet, then the option is available until I actually do the import of a text file, and then the option is greyed out once again.
Is there a solution for this behaviour?
I cannot use the newer way of importing data as that creates a table and destroys all my conditional formatting in the process. And there's no way to tell Excel to 'import the data, create a table but retain conditional formatting'.
I have search this site and others for similar issues but no solution yet...
Any ideas?
Thanks

I don't know if this suggestion will help you or not. I was facing a similar problem. Then I found out that when I click on a blank cell and then go to the legacy wizard, it works.
